# How to do a paged query using ScalaQuery?

Tags: scala, scalaquery

I have a query that returns `Person` objects that I’m using to fetch one page of results from the database:

```
def page(pageNumber:Int, pageSize:Int) : Seq[Person] = database.withSession {
  val query = for(person <- People) yield person.mapped
  val startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
  query.list.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize)
}
```

This works, but I want to know if I can do the paging in the database, in the same way as with the `javax.persistence.Query` API's `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` methods, instead of using `slice` on the resulting list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [tests](https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/scalaquery/test/PagingTest.scala) suggest using normal Scala collection methods like `drop` and `take`. Those will efficiently handle the JDBC ResultSet. It also [looks like](https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalaquery/ql/extended/PostgresDriver.scala#L50) the appropriate `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are added to the query.

Pipelines of operations on Scala collections may look like they're just filtering actual data, but as you can see here information can also travel back up the pipeline to make the computation as a whole more efficient.

Demonstration:

```
scala> import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.PostgresDriver.Implicit._
import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.PostgresDriver.Implicit._

scala> val q1 = Entities.map { e => e }.drop(10).take(10)
q1: org.scalaquery.ql.Query[models.Entities.type] = Query

scala> q1.selectStatement
res5: String = SELECT "t1"."guid","t1"."foo","t1"."bar" FROM "entities" "t1" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Note that you need to import one of the specific driver implicits to make this work. See the end of the [getting started guide](https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/wiki/Getting-Started) for a list of driver names.

Comment: Could you please show your imports? I've got a problem requiring me to use `take(Int)` but the compiler says it's not a member...